# Nginx - populate REQUEST_URI with rewritten URL

Tags: nginx, rewrite, php-fpm

I have an Nginx configuration that is for a new PHP application that has the same functionality as another legacy PHP application, but different URLs.

I want to preserve the paths of the old application, replacing the `/foo` path prefix with `/page` and replacing the special path `/foo/bar` with `/page/otherBar` :

```
    # legacy support
    location ~ ^/foo/bar {
        rewrite /foo/bar /page/otherBar$1 last;
    }

    # How to rewrite all other pages starting with "/foo" ?

    # END legacy support

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to front controller
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/www/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
```

This approach does not work, because `$request_uri`, which gets passed to `REQUEST_URI` in the `fastcgi_params` include file, still contains `/foo/bar`.

I've tried setting `REQUEST_URI` to `$fastcgi_path_info` but that fails for all non-rewritten URLs as it is empty then. `$uri` also does not work because it just contains `/index.php?`

Is there any variable for the third location config that contains the rewritten path?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$request_uri` has the value of the original URI and `$uri` has the value of the final URI. You could use the `set` directive to save a snapshot of `$uri` from inside the `location /` block and use it later to generate the `REQUEST_URI` parameter.

Like this:

```
location / {
    set $save_uri $uri;
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    include  fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI $save_uri;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#set) for more.

Comment: Thank you! My original config can even be improved by adding the rewrite rules into the `location /` block (before setting the variable)

Comment: Some time ago I used the same approach to use the modified URI. All works well, but now I encountered an issue with encoded `#` in the URL: `/foo/bar%23baz`. In PHP I get now `/foo/bar#baz`, which I don't expect.
Without rewriting the `REQUEST_URI`, I get the encoded `#` as `%23`, which I expect. Is there a way to disable this decoding?